# Identifying sockets source machine

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, server

Let's say that I have a website which uses a socket connection to comunicate with the server. And also a software (may be a n O.S service or even a desktop software) that also communicates with the same server.

Is it possible to the server to check if these two connections came from the **same machine**?

I do know that it's possible by using **session id** in case of two sockets that come from two different tabs in a browser, but I do not know how to procceed in case of one socket coming from the browser by using socket.io for example, and another socket coming from a desktop software or a O.S background service...

Thanks!

Comment: There are, IMHO, too many possible variations to know for sure. IP and MAC addresses aren't any help (intermediaries, gateways etc'), which leaves the option of a client certificate installed on the machine (somewhat impractical when having multiple possible clients, but if you really need it, it might be the way to go).

Comment: @Myst Thanks for your answer, I liked the option of looking for the clients certificate. What is the reason that could make it impractical when dealing with many possible clients?

Comment: I might be wrong about how practical / impractical it might be, but it gets harder to control the certificate installation and enforce it’s usage when there’s a number of possible clients sharing a machine.

Comment: @Myst Nice. Thanks a lot!  I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these connections are coming from the same computer, then there is a high probability that the source IP address would be the same.  There would have to be something like multiple network adapters in the computer or separate proxy routing or something unusual like that for the IP address to not be the same.

But, the converse is a problem because connections from different computers on a private network (home or work networks) may all go through the same gateway and thus connections from different computers on that private network may appear to have the same IP address.

So, you can't uniquely identify whether it is precisely the same computer by examining IP address.

If both connections were from a browser, you could cookie the first one with a unique cookie and you could check the second connection to see if it had the same cookie.  But, if one of the clients is not a browser, then it won't share cookies with the other one.  It is these cookies that allow sessions IDs to identify two tabs in a browser as being the same user.

> Is it possible to the server to check if these two connections came from the same machine?

Not conclusively just based on the connection all by itself.  You can identify if they might be the same computer, but can't conclusively prove that they are without other help.

The usual solution to a problem like this is to have the user create an account with your service and have each connection provide some login or at least identity credentials that you can then use to identify which connections belong to which computer.  For the desktop app, creating this login can be part of the setup process and then the credentials can be saved locally and automatically used.  For the browser, the user may have to enter the credentials the first time and then a lasting cookie can keep them saved for a duration.

---

Here's another scheme.

1. The local desktop app or OS service can coin a unique ID.  That will be the `serviceID` for the external automation machine that is connected to the computer.
2. That same local service will run a web server on a known port (let's just say it's on port 9333 for example here) that allows CORs requests.
3. The local browser can then connect directly to the local service by making a connection to `http://localhost:9333` to load a web page and then just directly control it from that web page or it can make an Ajax call to `http://localhost:9333/fetchID` to get the ID of the local service and then it uses that in any communication with your main server so that there's no doubt about which service is on the same computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Yeah! I was also thinking on using Login authentication in both browser and service so that it could make the issue a lot easier to nail down, I was only trying to figure it out if there might be a problem if the same user logged in two browsers from two different computers and coincidentally these two computers has an instance of the service logged in and running in each one... What do you think?

Comment: @user1990231 - I can't tell you if that would be a problem.  You'd have to tell me as I have no idea what your service is doing or what the consequences of that are.  You can detect different IP addresses on the same account and prevent that which would catch many (though not all) cases of the same account being used on separate computers.

Comment: Yeah, you right!
The point is that this setvice will be responsible to control an external automation machine and the idea is to use the system running in the browser to communicate with the server and the server to communicate with the automation machine through the reffered service.

Comment: @user1990231 - Why don't you just have the browser communicate directly with the local service process?  If the service runs a local web server on a known port, then the browser can just connect to `http://localhost:nn` and there's never a doubt.

Comment: I can use a separate socket for the browser to communicate with the service as you said and it would not be a problem, but when the machine finishes its job, the service needs to send the outcome to the server to compute and the server needs to send the result of this computing to the client to see it. That&#39;s tge reason I need to identify what is the sockets that comes from the same machine., So that the server will know what socket he needs to send the result back to.
But your suggestion gave me an idea...

Comment: The idea is take advantage of the socket we used to communicate the browser with the server and then share a random code that the browser can use to issue the result from the server, so that the server knows the destination by the code.
Thanks!

Comment: @user1990231 - See the description I added to the end of my answer.  The idea is to connect to `http://localhost:nnn` and get an ID from the local service as THE conclusive way to connect the two.

Comment: Sorry I did not read your whole answer. So that seems to be the simplest and workable solution.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep! I just did!